# close sqf in flutter

Tags: sql, flutter, dart

if i have a ListView to show a data from sql .
1)where should i But this function to close database?
2)_Close function is enough to close it or i need to use async??

```
 void _Close(Database db)  {
     db.close();
  }
```

this is my Listview:

```
 ListView getStudentsList() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
          return Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: isPassed(this.studentsList[position].pass),
                child: getIcon(this.studentsList[position].pass),
              ),
              title: Text(this.studentsList[position].name),
              subtitle: Text(this.studentsList[position].description + " | " +
                  this.studentsList[position].date),
              trailing:
              GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.grey,),
                onTap: () {
                  _delete(context, this.studentsList[position]);
                },
              )
              ,
              onTap: () {
                navigateToStudent(this.studentsList[position], "Edit Student");
              },
            ),

          );
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an async function to ensure that the database has been closed before the UI changes:

```
 Future<void> _close(Database db) async {
     await db.close();
  }
```

This function can be put anywhere in the scope of the `db` variable, and you should call it with the code `await _close();` when you are finished reading from the database.

Comment: if i want to close database after closing the app what should i do?

Comment: @MariamAlbarghouti unfortunately code does not run after closing the app. You could close the database right after getting all the data you need from it. However, I'm not sure what kind of database you're using, it may close automatically. If there is no error or warning generated when you do not close the database, then you probably don't need to worry about closing the database.

Comment: i'm using sql database

Comment: @MariamAlbarghouti SQLite? SQL is a standard database language, many different databases use it. I think you should try not closing the database at all to see what happens.

Comment: yeah i'm using SQLite

Comment: @MariamAlbarghouti see what happens when you don't close the database